# Give a counterexample to show that W is not a subspace of C[-1,1]

Tags: linear-algebra

I am having some trouble finding a counter example for the below. IF anyone could help me out by providing one I would greatly appreciate it.

This question comes directly from the textbook Linear Algebra Gateway to Mathematics by Robert Messer.

**Question:**
Let $W=\{f∊C[-1,1] | f(-1)=0 \lor f(1)=0\}.$ Give a counter example to show that $W$ is not a subspace of $C[-1,1].$

I suspect this fails under scalar multiplication but I'm having a hard time creating a counterexample.

Thanks again for any help.

Comment: Take two functions, each with one free boundary condition. That should be enough.

Comment: My edit was for formatting and a bit of punctuation. The word "subspace" is ambiguous . I believe what you mean is "vector subspace"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f_1(x)=1+x\\
f_2(x)=1-x\\
f_1+f_2\notin W$$

Actually, $W$ is closed under scalar multiplication.

Comment: I think i understand where you are going. Would you say this proof is equivalent to what you posted? 

let f(x)=1+x, let g(x) = 1-x |
1+x+1-x = 2 |
2 ∉ [-1,1] hence 2 ∉ W |
Therefor it fails under addition.

Comment: To the proposer: Yes that is exactly "it".

Answer (score 0):

Well, this notation is horribly tortured.

Is $f$ in $W$ if and only if both equations $f(-1) = 0$ AND $f(1)=0$ hold? That's how it looks from how it was written. In which case then YES, $W$ is indeed a subspace.

Or is $W$ the set generated by (i.e., linear combinations of) the
set

$\{f \in C[-1,1]$ such that $f(-1) = 0\}$ $\cup$ $\{g \in C[-1,1]$ such that $g(1) = 0\}$;

i.e., the set of functions $f$ such that EITHER $f(-1) = 0$ OR $f(1)=0$ (maybe both but not necessarily)? In which case NO, $W$ is not a subspace. Let $f(x) = x+1$, $g(x) = 1-x$, then $f+g = 2$, nonzero everywhere

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, it has definitely helped me see it a bit clearer. I pulled the question directly from my linear algebra book so its odd that the notation is off ( Linear Algebra gateway to mathematics by Robert Messer). Maybe that's why I'm having a bit of trouble with it.

Comment: The downward wedge $\lor$ does mean "or".